# Run airflow process and airflow webserver as airflow user

Tags: google-cloud-platform, centos7, airflow

**Problem**: I am setting up a Google Compute Engine VM on GCP with `airflow` installed on it. I am now trying to integrate `airflow` with `systemd` by following instructions on http://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#integration-with-systemd, however it states an assumption that Airflow will run under `airflow:airflow`.

How can I set the airflow installation so that whenever any user on that VM runs `airflow` from the shell, on backend it runs as `airflow` user. It is similar to hive process running under hive user.

**OS on VM**: CentOS 7

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried actually following the directions as listed in the linked offical docs? I believe that as long as you use [Airflow supplied SystemD configs](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/master/scripts/systemd) all processes should start using `airflow:airflow`.

This happens in [these two lines](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/scripts/systemd/airflow-webserver.service#L21)

Of course this is assuming you are exclusively using systemd to start the services up. If you try manually running `airflow webserver` it will start as your current user.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure `default_impersonation` in the `core` section of your `airflow.cfg` to set all tasks to run as the `airflow` user by default. Once that is set, you'll just need to start the airflow webserver/scheduler/workers/flower (depending on your executor/setup) as the `airflow` user.

That should cover all the bases, however keep in mind for tasks, that just sets the default user, it can be overridden on a per DAG or task level