# How to use Airflow scheduler with systemd?

Tags: airflow

The docs specify [instructions for the integration](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/run-with-systemd.html)

What I want is that every time the scheduler stop working it will be restarted by it's own.  Usually I start it manually with `airflow scheduler -D` but sometimes it stops when I'm not available.

Reading the docs I'm not sure about the configs.

The [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/master/scripts/systemd) contains the following files:

```
airflow
airflow-scheduler.service
airflow.conf
```

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04

Airflow is installed on:

```
home/ubuntu/airflow
```

I have path of:

```
etc/systemd
```

The docs says to:

> Copy (or link) them to /usr/lib/systemd/system

1. Copy which of the files?

> copy the airflow.conf to /etc/tmpfiles.d/

2. What is tmpfiles.d ?
3. What is `# AIRFLOW_CONFIG=` in the airflow file?

Or in another words... a more "down to earth" guide on how to do it?

Comment: Not an actual answer to your question, but I find it easier to run Airflow with supervisord.

Answer (score 6):

Integrating Airflow with systemd files makes watching your daemons easy as systemd can take care of restarting a daemon on failure. This also enables to automatically start airflow webserver and scheduler on system start.

Edit the `airflow` file from `systemd` folder in [Airflow Github](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/master/scripts/systemd) as per the current configuration to set the environment variables for `AIRFLOW_CONFIG`, `AIRFLOW_HOME` & `SCHEDULER`.

Copy the services files (the files with `.service` extension) to `/usr/lib/systemd/system` in the VM.

Copy the `airflow.conf` file to /etc/tmpfiles.d/ or /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/. Copying `airflow.conf` ensures `/run/airflow` is created with the right owner and permissions (`0755 airflow airflow`). Check whether `/run/airflow` exist with `airflow:airflow` owned by airflow user and airflow group if it doesn't create `/run/airflow`folder with those permissions.

Enable this services by issuing `systemctl enable <service>` on command line as shown below.

```
sudo systemctl enable airflow-webserver
sudo systemctl enable airflow-scheduler
```

`airflow-scheduler.service` file should be as below:

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow scheduler daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/airflow
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/airflow scheduler
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Why should we copy the `.service` file to `/usr/lib/systemd/system` as opposed to for example `/etc/systemd/system`?

Comment: Another question: Does it make a difference to using systemd if airflow is installed locally in a virtual environment vs installed globally?

Comment: How did you solve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291335/run-airflow-process-and-airflow-webserver-as-airflow-user. I'm getting permission denied

Comment: @Newskooler No it should not make any difference if you airflow is installed in virtualenv. The Only thing you need to do in that case is activate the VirtualEnv in the `.service` file

Comment: Can I do this without `systemd`? Trying to set this up using WSL which does not come with systemd

Answer (score 1):

Your question dates a little, but I just discovered it, because I'm interested at the moment in the same subject. I think the answer to your question is here.

https://medium.com/@shahbaz.ali03/run-apache-airflow-as-a-service-on-ubuntu-18-04-server-b637c03f4722