# run Airflow webserver on EC2 Centos using Systemd: Permission denied

Tags: amazon-ec2, airflow, systemd

I'm using [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) in EC2 CentOS with [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) to manage daemons for starting airflow processes (ie: webserver, worker and scheduler). 
When I run `sudo systemctl start airflow-webserver`

```
: ec2-user : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl enable airflow-webserver
Oct 30 01:27:37 ip-171-32-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal sudo[11680]: ec2-user : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start airflow-webserver
Oct 30 01:27:37 ip-171-32-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[11684]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/ec2-user/.local/bin/airflow: Permission denied
Oct 30 01:27:37 ip-171-32-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: airflow-webserver.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Oct 30 01:27:37 ip-171-32-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit airflow-webserver.service entered failed state.
Oct 30 01:27:37 ip-171-32-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: airflow-webserver.service failed
```

*airflow-webserver.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow webserver daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/airflow
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/.local/bin/airflow webserver --pid /run/airflow/webserver.pid
RestartSec=5s
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

airflow group and user are present:

```
$ less /etc/group
# airflow:x:1001:ec2-user
$less etc/psswd
# ec2-user:x:1000:1000:EC2 Default User:/home/ec2-user:/bin/bash
# tss:x:59:59:Account used by the trousers package to sandbox the tcsd # daemon:/dev/null:/sbin/nologin
# airflow:x:1001:1001::/home/airflow:/bin/bash
```

[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291335/run-airflow-process-and-airflow-webserver-as-airflow-user) does not help.

***UPDATE***

after creating an `airflow` user and installing airflow under `usr/local/bin` then changing the `ExecStart` to `usr/local/bin/airflow webserver --pid /run/airflow/webserver.pid`   I was able to get passed the initial permission denied. However now I get this error:

```
Oct 31 18:44:12 ip-172-31-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal airflow[31430]: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '${AIRFLOW_HOME}'
Oct 31 18:44:12 ip-172-31-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal airflow[31430]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Oct 31 18:44:12 ip-172-31-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal airflow[31430]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Oct 31 18:44:12 ip-172-31-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal airflow[31430]: File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 25, in <module>
Oct 31 18:44:12 ip-172-31-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal airflow[31430]: from airflow.configuration import conf
Oct 31 18:44:12 ip-172-31-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal airflow[31430]: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
Oct 31 18:44:12 ip-172-31-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal airflow[31430]: from airflow.utils.log.logging_mixin import LoggingMixin
Oct 31 18:44:12 ip-172-31-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal airflow[31430]: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
Oct 31 18:44:12 ip-172-31-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal airflow[31430]: from .decorators import apply_defaults as _apply_defaults
Oct 31 18:44:12 ip-172-31-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal airflow[31430]: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/decorators.py", line 34, in <module>
Oct 31 18:44:12 ip-172-31-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal airflow[31430]: from airflow import settings
Oct 31 18:44:12 ip-172-31-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal airflow[31430]: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 36, in <module>
Oct 31 18:44:12 ip-172-31-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal airflow[31430]: from airflow.configuration import conf, AIRFLOW_HOME, WEBSERVER_CONFIG  # NOQA F401
Oct 31 18:44:12 ip-172-31-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal airflow[31430]: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 523, in <module>
Oct 31 18:44:12 ip-172-31-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal airflow[31430]: mkdir_p(AIRFLOW_HOME)
Oct 31 18:44:12 ip-172-31-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal airflow[31430]: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 505, in mkdir_p
Oct 31 18:44:12 ip-172-31-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal airflow[31430]: 'Error creating {}: {}'.format(path, exc.strerror))
Oct 31 18:44:12 ip-172-31-6-92.us-east-2.compute.internal airflow[31430]: airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: Error creating ${AIRFLOW_HOME}: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are trying to run as `airflow` user but that path to `airflow` binary is in `/home/ec2-user/.local/bin/airflow` which is a HOME directory for `ec2-user`.

Install airflow in a directory where your `airflow` users have permission to.

Comment: I created an airflow user and group. Installed airflow through this user then ran systemd but still get this error" `Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/airflow/.local/bin: Permission denied`